# How to get data from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I try to select some parts of course:

```
  def index
    course = Course.find params[:course_id]
    @parts = course.parts
    respond_with @parts
  end
```

My course model:

```
class Course
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :description

  has_many :course_progresses
  has_many :groups
  has_many :parts, dependent: :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts

  def group_for(user)
    return nil if user.nil?
    groups.where(student_ids: user.id).first
  end

  def status_for(user)
    return :in_progress if user && user.has_course?(self)
    :new
  end
end

class Part
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name

  belongs_to :course

  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :units

  validates_presence_of :name, :course
end
```

But :corse_id are **nil** so i have this error:

> Problem: Calling Document.find with nil is invalid. Summary:
>   Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will
>   return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of
>   documents if multiple ids are provided. Resolution: Most likely this
>   is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the
>   parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed
>   is incorrect.

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371085/calling-document-find-with-nil-is-invalid-mongoid-in-rails-4

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I did missed this when looking for answer